# Effectively query on column that includes a substring

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Given a string column with a value similar to `/123/12/34/56/5/`, what is the optimal way of querying for all the **records that include the given number** (`12` for example)?

The solution from top of my head is:

`SELECT id FROM things WHERE things.path LIKE '%/12/%'`

But AFAIK this query can't use indexes on the column due to the leading `%`.

There must be something better. What is it?

Using PostgreSQL, but would *prefer* the solution that would work across other DBs too.

Comment: It would be better not to have a multivalued field :)

Comment: I can go with additional table 'thing_paths' with path in it. Then join it and query it ~ `select DISTINCT things.id from things inner join thing_paths on thing_path.thing_id = things.id WHERE thing.path LIKE '/12/%'`. But at this stage it is more than I ideally want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 9.1 you could utilize the [`pg_trgm` module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html) and build a GIN index with it.

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm; -- once per database

CREATE INDEX things_path_trgm_gin_idx ON things USING gin (path gin_trgm_ops);
```

Your `LIKE` expression can use this index even if it is not left-anchored.

See a detailed [demo by depesz here](http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/).

Normalize it If you *can*, though.

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know. The write performance is dramatically slower though.

Comment: RE normalisation. This column is used in pretty much one or two places only, not sure whether the normalisation is worth it yet. Have to think more about it.

Comment: RE normalization: The normalized form will probably be dramatically faster.

Answer (score 4):

If you're happy turning that column into an array of integers, like:

```
'/123/12/34/56/5/' becomes ARRAY[123,12,34,56,5]
```

So that `path_arr` is a column of type `INTEGER[]`, then you can create a GIN index on that column:

```
CREATE INDEX ON things USING gin(path_arr);
```

A query for all items containing 12 then becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM things WHERE ARRAY[12] <@ path_arr;
```

Which will use the index.  In my test (with a million rows), I get plans like:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM things WHERE ARRAY[12]  <@ path_arr;
                                      QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on things  (cost=5915.75..9216.99 rows=1000 width=92)
   Recheck Cond: (path_arr <@ '{12}'::integer[])
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on things_path_arr_idx  (cost=0.00..5915.50 rows=1000 width=0)
         Index Cond: ('{12}'::integer[] <@ path_arr)
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's another option. But AFAIK it is technically the same as `LIKE` + GIN index as Erwin suggested, just expressed differently.

Comment: It is another GIN index.  But it's one that more closely corresponds to the actual data.  In principle the index will be more efficient because it won't be recording items containing "27/" and "1/2", etc.

Comment: Edmund, I accepted Erwin's answer simply because it was simpler (didn't have to change any code yet). But I wish I could accept 2 answers since your solution is more elegant.

Comment: There is often a tradeoff between pragmatism and elegance.  And the syntax for indexes over lists doesn't help, so I might have picked Erwin's answer too (tbh).  Thanks for your comment.