# Longest matching substring

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

How would you search for the longest match within a varchar variable? For example, table GOB has entries as follows:

```
magic_word |  prize
===================
         sh|  $0.20
        sha|  $0.40
       shaz|  $0.60
      shaza|  $1.50
```

I would like to write a plpgsql function that takes amongst other arguments a string as input (e.g. `shazam`), and returns the 'prize' column on the row of GOB with the longest matching substring. In the example shown, that would be `$1.50` on the row with magic_word `shaza`.

All the function format I can handle, it's just the matching bit. I can't think of an elegant solution. I'm guessing it's probably really easy, but I am scratching my head. I don't know the input string at the start, as it will be derived from the result of a query on another table.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does brac match abrac?

Comment: No, it has to match from the start. Bad choice of example, I'm sorry. I changed the word to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 5):

#### Simple solution

```
SELECT magic_word
FROM   gob
WHERE  'shazam' LIKE (magic_word || '%')
ORDER  BY magic_word DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

This works because the longest match sorts last - so I sort `DESC` and pick the first match.

I am assuming from your example that you want to match left-anchored, from the beginning of the string. If you want to match anywhere in the string (which is more expensive and even harder to back up with an index), use:

```
...
WHERE  'shazam' LIKE ('%' || magic_word || '%')
...
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6d7e3/1)

#### Performance

The query is not [sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable). It might help quite a bit if you had additional information, like a *minimum length* that you could base an index on, to reduce the number of rows to consider. It needs to be criteria that gets you less than ~ 5% of the table to be effective. So, initials (a natural minimum pick) may or may not be useful. But two or three letters at the start might help quite a bit.

In fact you could optimize this iteratively. Something along the line of:
Try a partial index of words with 15 letters+
If not found, try 12 letters+
If not found, try 9 letters+
...

A simple case of what I outlined in this related answer on dba.SE:

- [Can spatial index help a “range - order by - limit” query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query/22500#22500)

Another approach would be to use a trigram index. You'd need the additional module [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html) for that. Normally you would search with a short pattern in a table with *longer* strings. But trigrams work for your reverse approach, too, with some limitations. Obviously you couldn't match a string with just two characters in the middle of a longer string using trigrams ... Test for corner cases.
There are a number of answers here on SO with more information. Example:

- [Effectively query on column that includes a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168486/effectively-query-on-column-that-includes-a-substring/10168546#10168546)

#### Advanced solution

Consider the solution under this closely related question for *a whole table of search strings*. Implemented with a recursive CTE:

- [Longest Prefix Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715602/longest-prefix-match)

Comment: You seen you know your stuff, so Which is LIKEly to be quicker: the nested SELECT below, or this one? I can test it, but the size of the table makes the difference negligible. However, eventually the table will be significantly larger, and such performance issues may make a difference.

Comment: @BrenMcGuire: As long as indexes are not involved the simplest form wins, which should be my first query. But testing >> guessing. The key to better performance is index usage.

Answer (score 1):

How about

## 1

```
     select max(FOO.matchingValue)
     from
      (
        select magic_word as matchingValue
        from T
        where substr( "abracadabra", 1, length(magic_word)) = magic_word 
      )
      as FOO
```

## 2

```
select prize from
T
  join
  (
  select max(FOO.matchingValue) as MaxValue
     from
      (
         select magic_word as matchingValue
        from T
        where substr( "abracadabra", 1, length(magic_word)) = magic_word 
      )
      as FOO
) as BAR
on BAR.MaxValue = T.magic_word
```

Comment: How do I retrieve the `cost` field from that result set?

Comment: Just turn the above into an inline view following the same principle. I'll edit in a second.

Comment: It does the job okay, but something about it says 'non-optimal' to me.

Comment: As to cost: presumably in a real-world application you'd have another indexed column, e.g. [CONTEST], that could be used to reduce the innermost set of candidate magic_words to an easily managed number. The gathering of the innermost candidate set is where the optimzation, if any, must occur.