# Select longest matching substring using django ORM

Tags: django-orm

I have a question which is basically the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369566/longest-matching-substring) , except that I want to implement it using the Django ORM if possible.

The linked question says:

---

How would you search for the longest match within a varchar variable? For example, the_table has entries as follows:

```
magic_word |  prize
===================
         sh|  $0.20
        sha|  $0.40
       shaz|  $0.60
      shaza|  $1.50
```

I would like to write a plpgsql function that takes amongst other arguments a string as input (e.g. `shazam`), and returns the 'prize' column on the row of the_table with the longest matching substring. In the example shown, that would be `$1.50` on the row with magic_word `shaza`.

---

The answer I want to emulate in Django is

```
SELECT magic_word
FROM   the_table
WHERE  'shazam' LIKE (magic_word || '%')
ORDER  BY magic_word DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

... but I can't see how to do the "backwards" `LIKE` statement.

("Backwards" in the sense that it's the input variable that on the lhs of the `LIKE`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [implement a custom lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-lookups/), for example:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Field
from django.db.models import Lookup

@Field.register_lookup
class PrefixOfLookup(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'prefix_of'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return "%s LIKE (%s || '%%%%')" % (rhs, lhs), params

class Xyz(models.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def get_by_longest_match(keyword):
        qs = Xyz.objects.filter(magic_word__prefix_of=keyword).order_by('-magic_word')
        if not qs:
            return None
        else:
            return qs[0]

    magic_word = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

example of usage:

```
# python manage.py shell
>>> from testapp.models import Xyz
>>> Xyz.objects.filter(magic_word__prefix_of='shazam').order_by('-magic_word')[0].magic_word
'shaza'
>>> Xyz.get_by_longest_match('shazam').magic_word
'shaza'
```

Comment: Nice!    Would it be possible to make it absorb the order_by and selection, so it becomes _longest_prefix_of?    That'd be instant accept answer :)

Comment: Updated my answer. Embedded `order_by` in lookup will cause error, when multiple query conditions are used. I think it's better to define a simple wrapper method in model.

Comment: Plonked it in, in place of the raw sql, it "just worked"... and reads better.  Yay, thanks!